# evdev passthrough of mouse button 4 and 5

Tags: arch-linux, windows, kvm, qemu, mouse

I have a Windows 10 VM setup with KVM (qemu). I am passing through my mouse and keyboard input.
I looked up the device under `/dev/input/by-id/` and added them to the XML:

```xml
<input type="mouse" bus="virtio">
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0b" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</input>
<input type="keyboard" bus="virtio">
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x0c" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</input>
<input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
<input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
```

```xml
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:arg value="-object"/>
  <qemu:arg value="input-linux,id=mouse1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-event-mouse"/>
  <qemu:arg value="-object"/>
  <qemu:arg value="input-linux,id=kbd1,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Gaming_KB_Gaming_KB-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on"/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Gaming_KB_Gaming_KB-event-if01 -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Gaming_KB_Gaming_KB-event-kbd -> ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Gaming_KB_Gaming_KB-if01-event-kbd -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-event-if01 -> ../event10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-event-mouse -> ../event6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-if01-event-kbd -> ../event7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-if02-event-kbd -> ../event11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  7 08:26 usb-Razer_Razer_DeathAdder_Elite-mouse -> ../mouse0
```

All inputs are working perfectly fine, except mouse button 4 and 5. They sometimes work, after an undefined amount of restarts of the vm.
How do I get my mouse button 4 and 5 properly working on the vm?

Comment: Do you mean mouse **buttons** 4 and 5?

Comment: @rfmodulator yes

Comment: It looks like your VM has 3 keyboards and 3 mice. What input devices are listed in the Windows Device Manager inside the VM?

Comment: I updated the post and added my output of  ```ls -lap /dev/input/by-id```. Another thing I noticed is, that when restarting the VM from within, the buttons work, but when started / restarted through my vm manager, they do not work. It's not optimal that way, but acceptable and reassuring that I did the configuration correctly.

Comment: I am trying to set up a keyboard and mouse pass through. Could you tell me where you include the first block of your code? I have something similar to the second block in my XML, but not the first.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The first block needs to be in the `<devices>` section. The second block must be within the `<domain>` section.

Comment: @RatzzFatzz thanks! Am I correct to understand that the first block is only needed to improve synchronization for gaming? That is, it is not vital to getting inputs to pass through?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I needed both parts for it to work properly, but on the other hand I can't recall trying it without the first block.